# Camel idempotentConsumer cannot retrieve values from the properties file

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to get value from properties for **removeOnFailure** as below: but can't

tried with ${} and {{}}} nothing works.

```
<idempotentConsumer messageIdRepositoryRef="infinispanRepo"  removeOnFailure="{{infinispan.hotrod.client.removeOnFailure}}">
```

Application.properties

```
infinispan.hotrod.client.removeOnFailure=false
```

Comment: are you configuring in xml or dsl?

Comment: Can you tell which version of Camel, and show how you have setup the properties placeholder. And when you say "dont work" what really happens.

Comment: Its XML (Spring DSL), Camel Version 2.19